# Update numbers with a counter in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table containing increasing and irregularly incremented numbers (3, 4, 7, 11, 16,...) in the first column *col1*.

I want to update *col1* such that the numbers will be 1000 plus the row number. So something like:

```
UPDATE tab1 SET col1 = 1000 + row_number()
```

I am using Oracle SQL and would appreciate any help! Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So, instead of the values 3, 4, 7, 11, 16 you want the result to be 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: You marked an answer as "correct" but is it really? That answer will assign the new values 1001, 1002 etc. with no relation to the values in `col1` - the number 1001 may be assigned to any of the rows in the table, not to the one with the smallest value in `col1`. Is that really what you need? It's not what you said!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, the simplest method might be to create a sequence and use that:

```
create sequence temp_seq_rownum;

update tab1
   set col1 = 1000 + temp_seq_rownum.nextval; 

drop sequence temp_seq_rownum;
```

Comment: The OP seems to want the rows to be re-numbered using the existing order given by the values in `col1` - how is a sequence going to guarantee that?

Comment: Besides, if in fact the OP doesn't care about preserving order, and only wants to assign sequential values to `col1`, your method is certainly not the simplest. For example: `update tab1 set col1 = 1000 + rownum` is much simpler and much faster.

Answer (score 0):

At the time I am posting this, a different answer is already marked as "correct". That answer assigns values 1001, 1002 etc. with no regard to the pre-existing values in `col1`.

To me that makes no sense. The problem is more interesting if the OP actually meant what he wrote - the new values should follow the pre-existing values in `col1`, so that while the numbers 1001, 1002, 1003 etc. are not the same as the pre-existing values, they still preserve the pre-existing **order**.

In Oracle, `row_number()` is not allowed in a straight `update` statement. Perhaps the simplest way to achieve this task is with a `merge` statement, as demonstrated below.

For testing I created a table with two columns, with equal values before the update, simply so that we can verify that the new values in `col1` preserve the pre-existing order after the update. I start with the test table, then the `merge` statement and a `select` statement to see what `merge` did.

```
create table t (col1, col2) as
  select  3,  3 from dual union all
  select  4,  4 from dual union all
  select 16, 16 from dual union all
  select  7,  7 from dual union all
  select  1,  1 from dual
;

Table T created.


merge into t
  using ( select rowid as rid, 1000 + row_number() over (order by col1) as val
          from   t) s
  on    (t.rowid = s.rid)
when matched then update set col1 = val;

5 rows merged.


select * 
from   t
order  by col1
;

   COL1    COL2
------- -------
   1001       1
   1002       3
   1003       4
   1004       7
   1005      16
```